# htaccess profile URLs vs page URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a website using friendly URLs. We want to have `www.website.com/johndoe` go to John Doe's profile, but we also use the `www.website.com/somepage` form to point to pages like `www.website.com/somepage.php`. How can we accomplish this? (a physical .php page should take precedence over a user page - we'll be disallowing certain usernames anyways)

```
# Redirect all URLs to the corresponding PHP page
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ $1.php [L]

# And if that's not found, try a user's profile
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You might want to have it go through `/user/johndoe` just in case...

Comment: Also, what happens when I hit `/profile.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The `-f` pattern [means](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) "is a physical file." Not sure off the top of my head if `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` works as I'd expect though.